# gwtupload for gwt 2.5.1 costum file upload

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

I'm trying to use [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) library and I'm using gwt version 2.5.1. their download page GwtUpload 0.6.6 library is compatible with gwt 1.6.4, 1.7.x, 2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.5.0. so no 2.5.1. So it's not possible to use it in my app, or is compatible 2.5.0 enough? Any updates on that ?

When I try to run my app I'm getting an error:

```
[ERROR] [myApp] - Line 18: No source code is available for type gwtupload.client.SingleUploader; did you forget to inherit a required module?

import gwtupload.client.SingleUploader;

line 18: private SingleUploader uploadFile;
```

I'm hoping it's another problem than the version of gwt. thx for any help.

The reason I'm needing this library is to costumize my FileUploadForm (Button), so also thx for any new ideas or similar libraries.

Comment: I don't think there are problems with 2.5.1. Have you done the configuration steps described here? https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted

Comment: But also with Maven GWT and web.xml configurations steps are required.

Comment: yeah I added my dependencies into my pom.xml.

Comment: Have you configured the GWT module file (Xxx.gwt.xml)? have you updated the web.xml file?

Comment: my mistake, forgot the inherits in my .gwt.xml? stupid mistake. thx anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated from the comments the GWT module file was not configured in order to inherit the gwtupload module.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redesign your Button you might use a little trick there. 
Make sure your actual uploadbutton is out of sight (by setting css top,left:10000 or something).
Afterwards you can place your own customized Button to the place where the actual upload button is supposed to be.
The only thing you have to do now, is trigger your actual button clickevent, when your customized button is pushed.

There is a Formpanel and an FileUpload class directly delivered with GWT

Comment: Yeah I now thx, but thats not an elegant solution for my problem and I think it might create new issues in the future. so I'm searching for an sophisticated solution.